# How to use safe filter on custom Django tag?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates, vuejs3

I'm trying to implement a custom Django tag that will formulate an import statement in Javascript to load my vue3 app as well as its components template html files using a get request in axios.

The custom tag in my `templatetags` directory looks like this:

`templatetags/vuecomponents.py`

```
from django import template
from django.templatetags.static import static

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def v_load_app_component(app_name, script_name, components):

    components = components.strip("[]").split(", ")

    app_script = static(f"js/{script_name}.js")
    comps = [static(f"components/{name}.html") for name in components]

    return f"import {{{ app_name }}} from \"{app_script}?{components[0]}={comps[0]}\""
```

Right now it only loads the first component as I just want a prototype. The only issue is when I drop this into a template like so:

`createpost.html`

```
<script type="module">

        {% v_load_app_component "creator" "internalpostform" "[internalpostform]" %}
        // OUTPUTS:
        // import { creator } from &quot;static/js/internalpostform.js?internalpostform=internalpostform.html&quot;

        creator.mount("#app")

</script>
```

It outputs the relevant import statement as:
`import { creator } from &quot;static/js/internalpostform.js?internalpostform=internalpostform.html&quot;`

With the double quotes escaped. Even when I tried to apply the `safe` filter (`{% v_load_app_component "creator" "internalpostform" "[internalpostform]"|safe %}`) it still escaped the output of my custom tag function.

How can I make it to where the output of my custom tag doesn't automatically have symbols converted to html entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it after a little digging in Django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape). The `safe` filter is only for variables i.e. `{{ variable|safe }}` but does not apply to a tag `{% tag "argument"|safe %}`.

To prevent Django from escaping the output of a tag you simply use `{% autoescape off %}`

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {% v_load_app_component "creator" "internalpostform" "[internalpostform]" %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

This results in the desired behavior.